# Assigning a value to baseclass property and accessing it from child class causing the debugger to Force stop

Tags: c#, asp.net, automatic-properties

i have a Base class for properties

```
  public class Parameters
  {
    public string caption
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string subcaption
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string bgColor
    {
        get
        {
            if (bgColor == " ")
                return bgColor = "FFFFFF";
            else
                return bgColor;
        }
        set { bgColor = value; }
    }
 }
 //some other properties with default return values
```

and other class inherits from this class and has a method to return stringbuilder

```
    public class Bar : Parameters
      {
    public StringBuilder GetXML()
    {
        StringBuilder xmlData = new StringBuilder();
        xmlData.Append("<chart bgColor='" + bgColor + "'"
                     + " caption='" + caption + "'"
                     + " subcaption='" + subcaption + "'>");//mentioned here are some properties there are many in the xmldata.append function 
        return xmlData;
    }
      }
```

now some other class tries to access this method by declaring object

```
      Bar XML = new Bar();
            XML.caption = "Caption";
            XML.subcaption = "subcap"; //setting values properties which dont have default return values 
            XML.GetXML();
```

when the debugger enters GetXML method debugger force closes himself, is there any thing i am missing here
is it something related to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/f9b08dd4-8d20-4104-9a24-9f002caceb48/)

Comment: Have you tried stepping into the method?  Or using "Break on all exceptions?"  It sounds as though your application is terminating cleanly, rather than crashing, so perhaps your code is swallowing the error silently.

Comment: @DanPuzey-yes,i did try stepping into method.but the debugger wont allow me to move forward,when i try to see the object value,using debug value checker it shows function evaluation was aborted..i will try using "Break on all exceptions"

Comment: What do you mean, "the debugger won't allow you to move forward?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just broken code.

```
 return bgColor = "FFFFFF";
```

Will evaluate to boolean and not string.

You are also trying to use a non-existing backing field in your getter.

Try something like this:

```
private string _bgColor;
  public string bgColor
  {
     get
     {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_bgColor))
        {
           _bgColor = "FFFFFF";
        }

        return _bgColor;
     }
     set { _bgColor = value; }
  }
```